# Replacing several lines with a function call for plotting in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have code like this

where f = np.linspace(0.1,2,100,endpoint=True)
and
a = np.zeros((4,100))

```
plt1, = plt.plot(f,a[0],'b')
plt2, = plt.plot(f,a[1],'g')
plt3, = plt.plot(f,a[2],'r')
plt4, = plt.plot(f,a[3],'k')

lines = [plt1,plt2,plt3,plt4]

plt.setp(lines,linewidth=2.0)
```

How can I replace the above with a nice succinct function? Passing colors and the list a[0:3] so I have something like

lines = plt_list(f,a,colors)

Regards,
Lefti

Answer (score 0):

Using a list enumeration.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plt_list(f, arr, colors):
    assert len(arr) == len(colors)
    return [plt.plot(f, a, c)[0] for (a, c) in zip(arr, colors)]

def main():
    f = np.linspace(0.1,2,100,endpoint=True)
    arr = np.zeros((4,100)) 
    colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'k']

    lines = plt_list(f, arr, colors)
    plt.setp(lines,linewidth=2.0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you asked, but I don't know that you'd call my answer elegant:

```
plt.plot(*[e for w in zip([f]*4, a, ['b','g','r','k']) for e in w])
```

You can plot more than one line at a time with

```
plt.plot(x1,y1,fmt1, x2,y2,fmt2, ...)
```

(where the line format string `fmt` can just be a color as with `'r'` or can include line styles like `'r:'` or `'r--'`) so the rest is down to zipping and properly unzipping (and flattening) your arrays...